# MiniMax search recursion is not correct

Tags: c++11, recursion, minimax

I am trying to write an AI to play ConnectK (a connect 4 game which require to connect k pieces, and the gravity could be on or off). And here is my function to get the best move using Minimax algorithm.

```
struct MoveNode //This struct is defined in header file
{
    MoveNode() {};
    MoveNode(int Score) : score(Score) {}
    Move move;
    int score;
};

MoveNode AIShell::getBestMove(int depth, int player) {//Find the best move using MiniMax
    if (depth <= 0) 
        return MoveNode(heuristic());
    else if (boardIsFull() && getWinner() == 0)//Tie
        return 0;
    else if (getWinner() == AI_PIECE)
        return 100000;
    else if (getWinner() == HUMAN_PIECE)
        return -100000;

    std::vector<MoveNode> mds;

    for (auto i : getMoveList()) {//For each available move
        MoveNode md;
        md.move = i; //i is Move(col,row)
        gameState[i.col][i.row] = player;
        if (player == AI_PIECE) {
            md.score = getBestMove(depth - 1, HUMAN_PIECE).score;
        }
        else {
            md.score = getBestMove(depth - 1, AI_PIECE).score;
        }
        mds.push_back(md);
    }

    //Get the best move after recursion
    int best_move_index = 0;
    if (player == AI_PIECE) {
        int best_score = -1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < mds.size(); i++) {
            if (mds[i].score > best_score) {
                best_move_index = i;
                best_score = mds[i].score;
            }
        }
    } else if (player == HUMAN_PIECE) {
        int best_score = 1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < mds.size(); i++) {
            if (mds[i].score < best_score) {
                best_move_index = i;
                best_score = mds[i].score;
            }
        }
    }
    return mds[best_move_index];
}
```

The getBestMove() function seems doing something I am not quite expected. The function will try to get the best move before the recursion, and the AI turn and Human turn is not been recursively handled evenly. And I have spent quite some time debugging this function but still can't figure it out. Sorry about my bad English, but I would really appreciate a help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the best move index. A minimax tree must return the nodes value (best_score), not the best move. The only time you should return the best move is at the root node, so that the search terminates by giving you the best move.